# Send email to myself via Dialogflow CX

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I read into some documentation but it's just my lack of expertise of coding and everything that I don't understand what to do...

I have a chatbot on my website. If a customer is in the Chatbot I want to summarize all the information that the customer has entered. When the customer confirms by saying 'yes', I want that the chatbot will send me an email so I have the request in there so I can pick it up whenever I want at any moment of time. I just want that the last summarize before the confirmation is sended to me (or the whole conversation, whatever is easier).

I really don't have any experience with coding or anything else and everything that I try is by looking for information on this website but this I wasn't able to find. I use Dialogflow CX with my Chatbot.

Is there someone who can help me? Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Hi @RaymondDouwes, Can you clarify more on your use case? Which chatbot are you using on the website?

Comment: Hi :)!

I am using a chatbot based on CX and with Intercom? I checked something with MailNodler but it is trusted customer data and I won't like to send the info to a third party except my secured mailbox (or is it secure :O)?

Comment: You can integrate Dialogflow with Google Chat to send email following this [document](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/chatbots-dialogflow-hangouts#0). Let me know if it’s helpful?